# form submit with two actions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to create a page where the form submit will execute two actions. In index.php,First action is it will use ajax to send data to be saved in the database. Second action is it will change page to index1.php. The code I created successfully saves data to the database but it does not change to index1.php. What is the problem with my code?

index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var radio1 = $("input[name=group1]:checked").val();
var radio2 = $("input[name=group2]:checked").val();
var radio3 = $("input[name=group3]:checked").val();
var radio4 = $("input[name=group4]:checked").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = '&submit1='+ radio1 + '&submit2='+ radio2 + '&submit3='+ radio3 + '&submit4='+ radio4;

if(radio1==''||radio2==''||radio3==''||radio4=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>

<form action="index1.php" method="post">
                <hr>
                        <label>Alignment: </label>
                        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="5"> 5
                        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="4"> 4
                        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="3"> 3
                        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"> 2
                        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1"> 1
                        <hr>
                        <label>Blend: </label>
                        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="5"> 5
                        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="4"> 4
                        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="3"> 3
                        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="2"> 2
                        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="1"> 1
                        <hr>
                        <label>Warp: </label>
                        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="5"> 5
                        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="4"> 4
                        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="3"> 3
                        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="2"> 2
                        <input type="radio" name="group3" value="1"> 1
                        <hr>
                        <label>Overall: </label>
                        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="5"> 5
                        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="4"> 4
                        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="3"> 3
                        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="2"> 2
                        <input type="radio" name="group4" value="1"> 1
                <hr>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
 </form>
```

Comment: Use  `window.location.href = "index1.php";` in your ajax success

Comment: do a redirect in the success of your ajax

Comment: It appears there is an answer, if this answer resolved your problem, could you mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer? It helps the community know that this question has been resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change location after ajax success:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
        window.location = '/index1.php';
    }
});
```